# Commands in menu not executing, no error

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm trying to make a dropdownbutton using the Fluent ribbon, to show a menu of all tables available in my database. The menu is generated by using a List that is retrieved from the db into TablesList, which is then bound to the itemssource of the dropdownbutton.

So far so good, the menu is generated and tablenames are displaying correctly.

Now I want to bind every menuitem to a command that will load them in the CurrentTable using the command LoadTableCommand which will take the header of the current menuitem and use that to load the correct table.

Here is where the problem arises, the command is not executed and I don't seem to get any error or clue to why this is (or isn't) happening.

The only thing I can think of right now is maybe binding the commands in the viewmodel itself and then assigning that to the ItemsSource, but I have yet to find out how I would do this since my favorite search engine hasn't found a solution for me..

PS: DataManager class works correctly, if that might concern you.

Does anybody have an idea to where I'm going wrong here?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as always ;)

MainWindow.xaml

```
...
                <Fluent:DropDownButton Header="Table"
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding TablesList}">
                    <Fluent:DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding LoadTableCommand}" />
                            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Header}" />
                        </Style>
                    </Fluent:DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>
                </Fluent:DropDownButton>
...
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
...
    private DataManager dataManager = new DataManager("Data Source=db.sqlite");


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        TablesList = dataManager.GetTables();
        CurrentTable = dataManager.GetTable("PriceList");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="TablesList" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string TablesListPropertyName = "TablesList";

    private List<string> _tablesList = new List<string>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the TablesList property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> TablesList
    {
        get
        {
            return _tablesList;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_tablesList == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging(TablesListPropertyName);
            _tablesList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(TablesListPropertyName);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="CurrentTable" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string CurrentTablePropertyName = "CurrentTable";

    private DataTable _currentTable = new DataTable();

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the CurrentTable property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public DataTable CurrentTable
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentTable;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_currentTable == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging(CurrentTablePropertyName);
            _currentTable = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(CurrentTablePropertyName);
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand<string> _loadTable;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the LoadTableCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand<string> LoadTableCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _loadTable
                ?? (_loadTable = new RelayCommand<string>(
                                      table => LoadTable(table)));
        }
    }

    private void LoadTable(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        // CurrentTable = dataManager.GetTable(name);
    }
...
```

Comment: use Snoop to check your DataContext and Bindings at runtime. http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ <-- its a really nice tool and easy to handle :)

Comment: I've never done this before, could you maybe point me in the right direction on where I could find some kind of tutorial or explanation for this? Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the tool, I had no idea of its existence but this will really save me lots of time, and you guys since I'll be having less questions :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your TablesList is a list of strings - a string has no property LoadTableCommand. so you should correct your Command binding. use Element binding or RelativeSource binding to walk up the tree to the right datacontext.

Comment: Thank you for this, I thought I was automatically binding to the MainViewModel, but I was actually binding to the TablesList. I replaced this with:

<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Main.LoadTableCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />

And it works, although I'd like to know if this is what you mean or a correct usage?

Thanks for this anyways, it's much appreciated!

Comment: yes thats what i mean, i always forget the third option - the one you use - StaticResource :) and you always have to check 2 things when bindings dont work -> 1. DataContext 2. Binding Path :)